# How to trace GridView sorting error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got an error when I trying to click the header of a column of a GridView. However, I don't know how to find out what exception it brings.

So I want to ask how to find the error and adding a try catch to the event handler.

code:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="result" runat="server" 
              AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Basic">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false">
            <HeaderStyle />
            <ItemStyle  Width="330px"  />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" CssClass="" Text='Somethings'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="user" SortExpression="user" Visible="false">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="userID" runat="server" CssClass="" Text='something'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

And I also have a DataGridSortCommandEventHandler of that gridview.

C#

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.result.EditCommand += new DataGridCommandEventHandler(result_EditCommand);
        this.result.SortCommand += new DataGridSortCommandEventHandler(result_SortCommand);
        this.result.ItemDataBound += new DataGridItemEventHandler(result_ItemDataBound);
        this.result.DeleteCommand += new DataGridCommandEventHandler(result_DeleteCommand);
    }

  void dg_result_SortCommand(object source, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       // do nothing
    }
```

The error is the a page which shows "Something wrong...", so I want to find out what thing is wrong.

Comment: Try adding some details.  I closed off and formatted your "code" as you left it trailing off at `<asp:TemplateColumn>` which is really just the UI portion of the GridView.  You have no code, no error messages, and no actual detail of the issue at hand.

Comment: From the c# code, it looks like you are assigning the event handlers to a handler that doesn't exist.  `result_SortCommand` for example is the handler you are assigning to, yet your actual method is `dg_result_SortCommand`  Likely the other handlers are similarly misnamed.